# Django REST framework: Integrity error at app NOT NULL constraint failed: app_model.field_id

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to add a `created_by` foreign key field to a model and have it auto populate when the authenticated user creates an instance of that model. I'm failing to understand how to pass the authenticated user's `id` field to the `created_by` field on the model.

Aside from the `clinic` model, which has the `created_by` field, and the clinic serializer, I have a custom user which inherits the `AbstractUser` class and the custom user has it's own serializer.

I'm trying to do this with the rest framework.

I've deleted the database, migrations and re-did them again. I've tried changing the serializer field names thinking id might be `user_id` or something like that. I feel this is a simple fix but I'm at a loss.

Here is a shortened `clinic` model and its equally shortened serializer (defined in different files):

clinic:

```
class Clinic(models.Model):
    clinicname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='clinics',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

clinic serializer:

```
class ClinicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    created_by = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='created_by.id')
    class Meta:
        model = Clinic
        fields = ['clinicname','created_by']
```

The user:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True) 
    objects = CustomUserManager()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

user serializer:

```
class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    clinics = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Clinic.objects.all()) 
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['id', 'email', 'clinics']
```

And heres the full traceback if at all helpful:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/clinics/

Django Version: 4.2.3
Python Version: 3.11.4
Installed Applications:
['users.apps.UsersConfig',
 'api.apps.ApiConfig',
 'clinics.apps.ClinicsConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 328, in execute
    return super().execute(query, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

The above exception (NOT NULL constraint failed: clinics_clinic.created_by_id) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 56, in wrapper_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 104, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
    ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 242, in post
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 19, in create
    self.perform_create(serializer)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 24, in perform_create
    serializer.save()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 212, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 962, in create
    instance = ModelClass._default_manager.create(**validated_data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 658, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 814, in save
    self.save_base(
    ^
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 877, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
              
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1020, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(
              
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1061, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
           
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1805, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1822, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 102, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
           
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 328, in execute
    return super().execute(query, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /clinics/
Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: clinics_clinic.created_by_id
```

Again, I've tried redoing migrations, deleting the database, changing the id column name and still can't figure it out.

Edit:

The view is:

```
class ClinicList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Clinic.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ClinicSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,IsCreatorOrReadOnly]
    def create_clinic(self, serializer):
         serializer.save(created_by=self.request.user)
```

This post data is:

```
clinicname  

'test3'

email   

'test@test.com'

adress  

'123456 MMM st'

adressline2     

'#100'

city    

'Boston'

state   

'MA'

postcode    

'10017'

about   

'Hopefully works'

telehealth  

'Y'

payment     

'Cash'
```

Comment: please add post payload and the view. The error message says, that the required user id was not submitted to the database.

Comment: There's some additional arbitrary fields in the post data compared to the model definition as shown above, hopefully that doesn't cause confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your View method name seem to not match. Try it like this:

```
class ClinicList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Clinic.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ClinicSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,IsCreatorOrReadOnly]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
         serializer.save(created_by=self.request.user)
```

TIP: you can also remove created_by (class attr) from ClinicSerializer and include it in read_only_fields of Meta. That will make your code more clean.

TRACEBACK TIP: If you read your traceback carefully, you can actually see that the view calls self.perform_create() etc. Your method has never been called.

Comment: Wow I feel dumb, I though perform_create() was an arbitrary name and not a method I had to override. Teaches me to read the docs more carefully. Thanks!